# Undefined variable sent from Ajax to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method where my users can change their password,to a new one,requiring 2 variables,one is the new password,and the other,the repetition of the password.The thing is that when i call the method, it returns the string "undefined",and uses that string as the new password,saving it on the db.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangePwdEnt(string pwd, string repeatpwd)
    {
        if (pwd == null || repeatpwd == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Insira os campos obrigatórios";
        }
        else
        {
            if (pwd == repeatpwd)
            {
                changePwd_Entidades(Session["ID"].ToString(),pwd);
                return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "As palavras chave precisam de ser iguais";
            }
        }

        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

Script:

```
<script>

$('.alt-btn').on('click', function () {



    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '@Url.Action("ChangePwdEnt", "Home")?pwd=' +
        $('#Info_pwd').val() + '&repeatpwd=' + $('#Info_repeatpwd').val(),

        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },


        success: function (Changed) {
            if (Changed) {
                window.location = "Entidades";
            } else if (!Changed) {
                window.location = "LoginEntidades";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the id for the HTML fields you are using is right?

Comment: @crazyglasses god I'm so blind...was using the wrong model :c thank you very much for helping me with my stupidity hehe

Comment: Haha no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are  using incorrect id to get value of password field.

And instead of sending both password to code better approach would be just compare your both password values at client side and if they both are same then parse those values to code side other wise ask user to input  same password .

Answer (score 0):

That would be better to Send the data in the `data` parameter while you're using `POST` method

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ 
             'pwd': $('#Info_pwd').val(),
             'repeatpwd':$('#Info_repeatpwd').val()
           });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("ChangePwdEnt", "Home"),
    data: data,
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    },


    success: function (Changed) {
        if (Changed) {
            window.location = "Entidades";
        } else if (!Changed) {
            window.location = "LoginEntidades";
        }
    }
});
```

This is for using `POST` method. If you want to use `GET` method than it would be fine to pass data in `query string`.